Detect a "Esc" key while user take a input (scanf) in terminal on C language
So i want to a program that can end the program while user press an "esc" but the position is user do a scanf in terminal.
the code that i try like this
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    char name[100];
    printf("(press esc to exit)\n");
    printf("Enter Your Name: ");
    while(1){
        scanf("%s", name);
        if(_kbhit()){
            char c = _getch();
            if(c==27){
                printf("Exit\n");
                break;
            }   
        }
    }

}

but as you can see when run the code. When i press a esc key it doesn't work because the cursor is on the name variable. any clue to solve that?

scanf is not suitable for such task, and ESC may not be sent before other codes, but if you set terminal in certain modes. So use ncurses for such things (or other libraries)

or build you own keyboard input functions using VC's getch(), as you do. But without using scanf(), which is not very useful for user input anyway.

scanf is for scanning formatted data like it can be created using printf. Even if you expect line-based input, errors in user input may result in problems with scanf.

Note well that conio.h is non-standard, as are all the functions it declares.  If you want to learn C (as opposed to Microsoft's idiosyncratic C implementation specifically) then you should not rely on that header or those functions.

@JohnBollinger standard C input seems to be line-oriented, to its shame. You could say the same of termios, but there seems to be a mantra "Linux extensions good, Microsoft extensions bad." (although the latter often are, but conio.h isn't one of them).

@WeatherVane, perhaps there is some general antipathy towards Microsoft, which I'd say was earned, but that's not my motivation here.  I am a big proponent of standard C, and I think neophytes especially should be alerted to the distinctions between standard features and extensions provided by the particular implementation they happen to be learning on (including those common on Linux). Not because using extensions is inherently bad, but because when you lean on extensions, you may not be learning the skills you think you are.

@JohnBollinger agreed, and one of MS's worst crimes is to deluge the VC user with fake warnings about the scanf function family, which can swamp more relevant ones and cause the VC user to ignore them all, if they don't know how to defeat them.

I really really want you to understand that your question today is no longer all that relevant because the console is not relevant to anyone but programmers. These days nearly all user input is going through web pages and HTML, and in HTML 5 there are fields where one can specify what a valid input should look like. IMO learning HTML Input's pattern attribute will be much more useful than getting an answer to this question. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

The best solution -- in my opinion -- is to abandon scanf().  I understand this might go against your goal/wishes, so I'm presenting this as an option for educational purposes, and not necessarily as the best answer. However, you might like it and select it as an answer, and that's fine by me.
This code interrogates every key press via _getche(), and determines the key's suitability before permitting its character value to enter the name buffer.  Ie: if ESC key is detected, the event is treated as an abort and the character value is not entered into the name buffer.
If the ENTER key is detected, it is treated as the normal end of input, just as scanf() would do.  On completion, all the characters typed have been gathered in name buffer -- but not the ENTER key character value (or any other disallowed key value).
This code is tested by me just now in MS Visual Studio on the MS Windows 10 OS.
For the community: I understand there is a regrettable issue of portability here due to use of _getch() and _getche().  However, OP has provided code utilizing _getch(), and so I have aligned this response with the OP's request in this regard.  In general, any API which captures keys and waits for keypress may be substituted for _getch() and _getche(), hence resolving the issue of portability. The rest of the code is 100% portable, as far as I know.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() 
{
    char name[100];
    int offs =0, ch, done  = 0;

    printf("(press esc to exit)\n");
    printf("Enter Your Name: ");
    
    while(!done && offs < sizeof(name)-1)
    {
        /* Getch() with echo, so we see chars as they are entered -- like scanf()*/
        ch = _getche(); 
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 27: /* ESC key -- treated like an abort */
                printf("\nESC entered -- Exit\n");
                done = 1;
                offs = 0; /* Signal no chars to be retained (abort)*/
            break;

            case '\r':  /* Quit on ENTER key -- just like scanf()*/
                printf("\nENTER entered -- all done.\n");
                done = 1;
            break;

            case '\t':  /* TAB key -- Sample disallowed value. */
                printf("\nTAB detected -- not allowed.\n");
            break;

            default: /* Default action is to store the char, just like scanf()*/
                name[offs++]=ch;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(offs) /* Did we capture any chars? */
    {
        name[offs]='\0';  /* cap it for printf() */
        printf("\nYou Entered: %s\n", name);
    }

    _getch(); /* Pause for results - wait key press */

    return 0;
}



When i press a esc key it doesn't work because the cursor is on the name variable. any clue to solve that?

Why press an esc key it doesn't work probably is that scanf() function is blocking. What you can try to read characters one by one, check if the ESC key was pressed, and then build the input string from these characters.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    char name[100];
    int i = 0;
    printf("(press esc to exit)\n");
    printf("Enter Your Name: ");

    while (1) {
        if (_kbhit()) {  
            char c = _getch(); 

            // Check for ESC key
            if (c == 27) {
                printf("\nExit\n");
                break;
            }

            // Handle backspace (if needed)
            if (c == 8 && i > 0) {
                printf("\b \b");  // Move cursor back, print space, move back again
                i--;
            } else if (c == '\r' || c == '\n') {  // Check for Enter key to finish input
                name[i] = '\0';
                printf("\nYou entered: %s\n", name);
                break;
            } else if (i < sizeof(name) - 1) {
                name[i++] = c;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

